# Async WCF: One Request => n Results

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, request, response

Is it poosible with WCF to do one async request and get 0 to n responses?

Example:
when requesting a list of object i want to call wcfservice.GetObjects()
and as response i would expect on response for every object.

Comment: what pattern do you use ? Do you make N calls to the service ? or 1 Call and N responses ?

Comment: i would like to do 1 call and get n responses.

Answer (score 0):

Why dou you need that?
It's because the performance?

Couldn't you just paginate

Comment: I need it to get maximum profit out of asyncness.
I request list of objects (in my case data for a line series) and can react on every response (add the line series to the chart). the up to 32000 lineseries can contain 4000 and more datapoints per line.